# Fundamental theorem of calculus for monotone function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, almost-everywhere

Assume $F:(0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $F(x) = \int_0^xf(u) du$ where $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nonincreasing (not necessarily continuous) function (note that F is real-valued so it is assumed implicitly the integral is well-defined)

Is it true that $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere and its derivative is equal to $f$ almost everywhere (if $f$ were continuous, then this would hold everywhere by the fundamental theorem of calculus)?

Idea: $f$ is monotone so has countable number of discontinuities...

Comment: How do we know that the integral even exists?

Comment: Assumed implicitly (since F is a function whose codomain is the real numbers).

Comment: I think I will change the question to make it more accessible.

Comment: Just because a function takes values in the reals does not mean it is integrable. Take for example $1/x$.

Comment: No, he is saying that $F$ is real valued, meaning that $f$ is integrable ... but I agree that he could just say "$f$ is integrable" ...